# Caching a this reference

Tags: javascript, performance

Does it make sense to cache a reference to the this context in, say, a "class" function where `this` is heavily used?

I'm thinking that a minifier could then replace `self` with something shorter and it would result in a slightly smaller file size. Does this have any downsides, would you do it and if not, why not?

Example:

```
var Klass = function() {
  var self = this;

  self.foo = 'qux';
  self.bar = 'quux';
  self.foobar = true;
  self.foobaz = false;
}
```

Comment: You gain 12 removed characters (4*`elf`) by adding 11 characters (`var s=this;`)? Doesn't look like a good deal. Make it simple and use `this` everywhere, also to make the code more clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Performance wise I doubt there will be any significant difference. Hence I can fathom only two advantages to use `self` in place of `this`:

1. Minification of code.
2. `self` reference in nested functions.

## Minification of code

Using `self` has a declaration cost. Thus it makes no sense to use `self` if you're only going to declare a few parameters. Hence I wrote a script which calculates when it becomes viable to use `self` over `this`:

```
alert(test(0));

function test(n) {
    var thisFunction = createThisFunction(n).toString();
    var selfFunction = createSelfFunction(n).toString();
    if (selfFunction.length < thisFunction.length) return n;
    else return test(n + 1);
}

function createThisFunction(n) {
    var body = repeat(n, "this.x=null;");
    return new Function(body.join(""));
}

function createSelfFunction(n) {
    var decl = "var s=this;";
    var body = repeat(n, "s.x=null;");
    return new Function(decl + body.join(""));
}

function repeat(n, x) {
    if (n === 0) return [];
    else return [x].concat(repeat(n - 1, x));
}
```

The answer is... drumroll please: [four](http://jsfiddle.net/dB6VS/). This means that if you have declare three or fewer parameters then it's better to stick with `this`. If you have four or more parameters then it's better to use `self`:

1. With three parameters a function with `this` uses 2 characters less than a function with `self` when minified.
2. With four parameters a function with `this` uses 1 character more than a function with `self` when minified.

You can play around with the fiddle and verify my assertions for yourself: http://jsfiddle.net/dB6VS/

### Nested functions

Sometimes you need a nested function to be able to access the `this` parameter of its parent function. In this case you need to create a `self` variable anyway. Hence if you have any nested functions which need to access `this` then just switch to `self`.

In short nested functions which need access to `this` overrule the 4 declarations rule for `self`.

Comment: Minification of code: This only applies to unzipped code, which imho is important to consider, because if you are interested in getting every byte, the js code will be transmitted zipped.

Nested functions: I would consider this bad practice in cases where JavaScript (>JS 1.8) or a framework providing Function.bind

Comment: That's also why I assigned exactly four values in my example ;) So no real downsides except for declaration cost?

Comment: @Sonata so when delivered gzipped it would actually be smaller if there were no `self` variables?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can determine that without trying both scenarios for your particular code. Depending on the length of your code, the number of times a string is found, etc, the size of zip will change.

Comment: @hnrch02 If you don't consider gzipped code then you do save a few bytes using the above technique. See the following chart: http://gg.gg/jsmin For example if you have no parameters then you're just wasting 11 bytes. However for each additional parameter you're saving 3 bytes (which is why you need 4 parameters to save 1 byte). Hence the equation for number of bytes saved is `f(n) = 3 * n - 11`.

Answer (score 1):

1) Imho `var self = this` is a construct that (as a developer) I don't want to be bothered with: I don't want to change code to help a minifier. The code should only exist of lines that are needed to do the job.

2) I haven't seen an example (yet!) where the difference in file size was that great, that I would reconsider principle 1)

Comment: I agree with 1) and I don't like to have that in my code either, but neither UglifyJS nor the Google Closure Compiler do that automatically , so I wonder if this is considered a bad practice or, because of 2), it is just not worth the effort.